# django not picking up migration where managed = False

Tags: python, django

I have a simple web-app I'm trying to create to visualise some carbon data (to teach myself Django!)

As my data model is a little complex I use the `managed=False` and import a view from my postgres database where I wrangle my data.

When I first ran the migration I noticed I left in a field that I didn't have in my view, so naturally I changed it. Now when I run `makemigrations` for my app called `carbon` it says there are no changes.

What is the correct way to remedy this?

additionally, for some reason when I try to run an `orm` query to pull in some data it expected me to have an `id` field in my view, can someone explain this, if possible?

### models.py

```
class CarbonViewHour(models.Model):
    daily_hour = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    reading    = models.FloatField()
    #date       = models.DateField() This was removed 

    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'carbon_v_hourly_meter_readings'

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.reading}-{self.daily_hour}"
```

---

the change I made was to remove a field from `CarbonTimeView`

```
date       = models.DateField()
```

### views.py

```
class CarbonTimeView(TemplateView):
    
    template_name = 'carbon/chart.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['qsm'] = CarbonViewMinute.objects.all().order_by('date')
        context['qsh'] = CarbonViewHour.objects.all()
        context['title'] = 'Daily Carbon Data'
        return context
```

### SQL View.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS public.carbon_v_hourly_meter_readings;
CREATE VIEW public.carbon_v_hourly_meter_readings
AS 

with cte AS ( 
    SELECT  -1             as id  -- im not sure why but Django expected an ID field? 
        ,   t.hour_num as daily_hour
        ,   c.reading
        ,   c.meter 

    FROM public.carbon_carbon c 
    INNER JOIN public.d_time_long t -- time dimension 
        ON c.date::time = t.full_time          

    WHERE DATE(c.date)   = (select max(DATE(c.date))
                    FROM public.carbon_carbon c )

    )

    SELECT  id 
        ,   daily_hour
        ,   AVG(reading) as reading 
        ,   meter 
    
    FROM cte 

    GROUP BY id
        ,    daily_hour 
        ,    meter

    ORDER BY daily_hour;
```

Comment: happy to close if question needs more clarity but please provide some insight as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed)

---

Options.managed

> **If False, no database table creation, modification, or deletion operations will be performed for this model.** This is useful if the
> model represents an existing table or a database view that has been
> created by some other means. This is the only difference when
> managed=False. All other aspects of model handling are exactly the
> same as normal. This includes
>
> **Adding an automatic primary key field to the model if you don’t
> declare it.** To avoid confusion for later code readers, it’s
> recommended to specify all the columns from the database table you are
> modeling when using unmanaged models.

Django is also not capable to do any migrations to views, that is why they are generally left as unmanaged an used scarcely

Comment: Ah that makes sense, my work around was to remove the model and add it again with the changed schema. Are views from databases generally not used then ?